# Kafka consumer reading the data from beginning every 5 hours

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have kafka consumer to consume the data from kafka cluster. Inthe cluster we have four server and the topic has multiple partition. But every 5 to 6 hrs the  consumer start read the data from beginning without doing anthing. We trying to identify the issue in many way but nothing help. Can some help on this why the offset start read from the beginning on every 5 to 6 hrs ?

Comment: All default consumer properties ate used

Comment: How long is the retention period on your consumer offsets topic? Does your consumer actually commit an offsets?

Comment: Yeah we are using manual commit to commit the offset  post read the data from topic. Consumer offset reset is the default value of 1440 hrs.

Comment: I assume you have set `auto.offset.reset=earliest`?

Comment: Yes, but the cosumer does not stooped, while running stage itself the pointer move to the first offset and start consume it every 5 or 6hrs hrs once it's happening in prod

Comment: The consumer doesn't need to stop. It could rebalance and reset

Comment: We tried using one consumer and one partition on the prod eventhogh the reset is happenning...

Comment: One consumer can still "rebalance". Do you have a function calling `seekToBeginning()`? Or other CLI function/service calling `kafka-consumer-groups --reset-offsets`? My comments are the only thought I have. Maybe the consumer or broker logs can help you more. By default, this behavior should not happen, so some configuration, custom service, or other exception is causing this to happen.

Comment: No we are not using theese two on our source code. But we are executing the reset command manually in the server to pickup the data from the specific timestamp

Comment: Why do you need to do that manually? The same methods from that command can be used in client code. Otherwise, sounds like the timestamp you're providing is before the beginning of the topic, causing it to reset to the earliest available timestamp